# Keeping timer consistent during session

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to make a timer in jsp so that a user can be timed for an assessment 
but I want the time to be consistence even when user refreshes the page so the function for timing can only be invoked once user logs and not restart once page is refreshed. For example maybe if the user was on question one and the time is 40 second, when page is refreshed for instance when he moves to the next question, it should still continue counting 41, 42 , 43 etc. Is it possible to record time at runtime in jsp using javascript or servlet and keep consistancy of it be it hidden to the user or not. Any shed of light is highly appreciated. I have the following which wokrs fine but when I refresh it is restarted again.

```
<script>  
 <!--  
 <%  
   String clock = request.getParameter( "clock" );  
       if( clock == null ) clock = "60";  
 %>  
      var timeout = <%=clock%>;  
      function timer()  
        {  
        if( --timeout > 0 )  
    {  
     document.forma.clock.value = timeout;  
      window.setTimeout( "timer()", 1000 );  
   }  
    else  
      {  
     document.forma.clock.value = "Time over";  
       ///disable submit-button etc  
        alert("Sorry but time is up spud muhahahaha");
       }  
     } 

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the session object from your JSP to store the start time of your clock.
Calculate the diff to the current request time and populate that to your JS var "timeout"

If time is over and user makes a refresh (F5, Back Button) you may change the content of the page.

Probably you need a separate timer for each question.